# How to parse output to see if a string matches?

Tags: command-line, bash, imagemagick

**Challenge:** 
I need to parse the output from imagemagick's "identify" command to detect the presence of a particular string. If it doesn't exist, then I echo the filename to the screen.

**Background:**
I have roughly 100k thumbnail images ([Example thumbnail that needs to be analyzed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIf2G.png)). I need to inspect each thumbnail to ensure it was rendered correctly. Luckily, "rendered correctly" can be determined by the presence of red pixels in the thumbnail. Using imagemagick's "identify" command, I can output the colormap which will contain the line, "(255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red".

**Need:**
Using a bash script, I can easily get all the file names and iterate through them.  I need to figure out how to *silently* parse through the output and look for a string match and echo the filename if not found.

Specifically, what I'm looking to do is create a script that does the following:

1) finds all the *.png files in a particular directory.

2) for each file, run "identify -verbose" and *silently* pass the output to...

3) analyze the output to see if the string "(255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red" exists.

3a) if it does, I continue silently to the next file.

3b) if it does not, I echo the file name.

Ultimately, I'd be left with a short list of thumbnails that did not contain any red pixels and require manual inspection.

Any help creating this script would be *most* appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find files which don't have red pixels:

```
for i in *png; do identify -verbose "$i" | gawk -e "{print \"$i\", \$0}" | fgrep -q '(255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red' || echo $i; done
```

To find files which have red pixels:

```
for i in *png; do identify -verbose "$i" | gawk -e "{print \"$i\", \$0}" | fgrep -q '(255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red' && echo $i; done
```

The gawk command adds the filename to each line of output from the identify command. Using fgrep rather than grep just looks for exact text matches (quicker). The -q flag to fgrep tells it not to output any lines; just to set the status to success or failure.

The script should be safe for filenames which contain spaces.

Comment: Thanks so much, @nickcrabtree.  What about the inverse?  I want to print the name only if the string *doesn't* appear.

Comment: There, should be fixed now. A bit neater code too.